# Returning lastval of the table in redshift

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, rdbms, amazon-redshift

Anyone explain is there any method to return the last inserted id of the identity column of a table in redshift.

i tried

```
insert into table1(name, address) values(abc,NY) returning (id)
```

but its not working..

Comment: redshift is not supposed to be used for this purpose...

Comment: is there any other method for this?

Comment: `insert into table1(name, address) values(abc,NY); select max(id) from table1;`

Comment: @novabracket . I need a single query. for example if 5 of them inserting data in the table for all of them it should return the id of the inserted row.

Comment: This looks like an application rather than Data warehouse need on Redshift. You should probably stop doing this or do this in any other regular OLTP databases. If you can specify the exact need for doing this in Redshift, totally alternative solutions can be possible.